# Using the dynamic_cast operator

Tags: c++, inheritance, dynamic-cast

I'm trying to understand dynamic type casting.
How to properly implement the DrawAnimals and Talk To Animals functions using dynamic_cast?

DrawAnimals draws animals that can be drawn. Such animals implement the Drawable interface.
TalkToAnimals conducts a conversation with animals that can talk, that is, they implement the Speakable interface.

```
class Speakable {
public:
    virtual ~Speakable() = default;
    virtual void Speak(ostream& out) const = 0;
};

class Drawable {
public:
    virtual ~Drawable() = default;
    virtual void Draw(ostream& out) const = 0;
};

class Animal {
public:
    virtual ~Animal() = default;
    void Eat(string_view food) {
        cout << GetType() << " is eating "sv << food << endl;
        ++energy_;
    }
    virtual string GetType() const = 0;

private:
    int energy_ = 100;
};

class Bug : public Animal, public Drawable {
public:
    string GetType() const override {
        return "bug"s;
    }
    void Draw(ostream& out) const override {
        out << "(-0_0-)"sv << endl;
    }
};

class Cat : public Animal, public Speakable, public Drawable {
public:
    void Speak(ostream& out) const override {
        out << "Meow-meow"sv << endl;
    }
    void Draw(ostream& out) const override {
        out << "(^w^)"sv << endl;
    }
    string GetType() const override {
        return "cat"s;
    }
};

void DrawAnimals(const std::vector<const Animal*>& animals, ostream& out) {
    /*if (const Animal* r = dynamic_cast<const Animal*>(&animals)) {

    } else if (const Bug* c = dynamic_cast<const Bug*>(&animals)) {

    }*/
}

void TalkToAnimals(const std::vector<const Animal*> animals, ostream& out) {
    //?
}

void PlayWithAnimals(const std::vector<const Animal*> animals, ostream& out) {
    TalkToAnimals(animals, out);
    DrawAnimals(animals, out);
}

int main() {
    Cat cat;
    Bug bug;
    vector<const Animal*> animals{&cat, &bug};
    PlayWithAnimals(animals, cerr);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to explain for `DrawAnimals` and you can extended to other functions by yourself.

What you did here:

```
void DrawAnimals(const std::vector<const Animal*>& animals, ostream& out) {
    /*if (const Animal* r = dynamic_cast<const Animal*>(&animals)) {

    } else if (const Bug* c = dynamic_cast<const Bug*>(&animals)) {

    }*/
}
```

Is plain wrong for several reasons:

1. `animals` is a vector
2. If you intended an individual element, then because `&animals[i]` `(i = [0..animals.size()])` is a pointer to pointer (`Animal**`)
3. Because `dynamic_cast<const Animal*>(animals[i])` `(i = [0..animals.size()])` is the identity.

You need to work with each individual element of the vector:

```
void DrawAnimals(const std::vector<const Animal*>& animals, ostream& out) {
    for (auto animal : animals) {
        if (const Drawable* r = dynamic_cast<const Drawable*>(animal)) {
            // this animal is Drawable

        } else if (const Bug* c = dynamic_cast<const Bug*>(animal)) {
            // this animal is a Bug
            // only issue here: Bugs are also Drawable
            // so this code will never be reached
        }
    }
}
```

Question: Why are some animals `Drawable` and other don't?

Comment: Thanks! 
Answer: Lovecraft's creatures can be animals, but cannot be drawn (as an example) :)

Comment: Concerning that code that's never reached, just remove the `else`.